# Merge parent nodes if child nodes identical xml

Tags: c#, xml

Let me put the scenario:
If the 'Student' node has same child elements then merge the 'Student' node. In this case if the 'Name' node is found in other 'Student' nodes with same value then those 2 'Student' nodes need to be merged with unique elements. In this case the 'Name' node being identical comes 1 time and the 'Address' node coming 2 times. 
Also the input xml can have different set of child nodes and can have different names every time. 
 Below is Input xml

```
<Root>
        <Student>
          <Name>Tim</Name>
          <Address>
            <City>
              <Location1>MEL</Location1>
            </City>
          </Address>
        </Student>
        <Student>
          <Name>Tim</Name>
          <Address>
            <City>
              <Location1>DEL</Location1>
            </City>
          </Address>
        </Student>
        <Student>
          <Name>1</Name>
          <FatherName>Papa</FatherName>
          <Address>
            <Suburb>1</Suburb>
            <City>
              <Location1>HNL</Location1>
            </City>
          </Address>
        </Student>
        <Student>
          <Name>1</Name>
          <MotherName>Mom</MotherName>
          <Address>
            <City>
              <Location1>HNL</Location1>
            </City>
          </Address>
        </Student>
</Root>
```

Expected xml:

```
<Root>
        <Student>
          <Name>Tim</Name>
          <Address>
            <City>
              <Location1>MEL</Location1>
            </City>
          </Address>
          <Address>
            <City>
              <Location1>DEL</Location1>
            </City>
          </Address>
        </Student>
        <Student>
          <Name>1</Name>
          <FatherName>Papa</FatherName>
          <Address>
            <Suburb>1</Suburb>
            <City>
              <Location1>HNL</Location1>
            </City>
          </Address>
        </Student>
        <Student>
          <Name>1</Name>
          <MotherName>Mom</MotherName>
          <Address>
            <City>
              <Location1>HNL</Location1>
            </City>
          </Address>
        </Student>
</Root>
```

I tried to implement with the below code. I know its not very efficient.

```
var newdoc = XDocument.Parse(input);
// 'restriction' is the concerned node 
foreach (var element in newdoc.Descendants("restriction")) 
{
            if (skiptimes > 0)
            {
                skiptimes--;
                continue;
            }
            //Get distinct node names for 'element'
            var distinctNodeName = element.Elements().Select(cc => cc.Name).Distinct();
            //delete if found 'freetext' node as the this do not need to be comapared
            distinctNodeName = distinctNodeName.Where(n => n.LocalName.ToString() != "FreeText");
            //Get distinct elements
            var distinctElementName = element.Elements().Select(xx => xx).Distinct();
            foreach (var nextelement in element.ElementsAfterSelf())
            {
                if (!nextelement.IsEmpty)
                {
                    //Get distinct node names for 'nextelement'
                 var distinctNodeName2 = nextelement.Elements().Select(xx => xx.Name).Distinct();
                    //delete if found 'freetext' node as the this do not need to be comapared
         distinctNodeName2 = distinctNodeName2.Where(n => n.LocalName.ToString() != "FreeText");
                    //Get distinct elements
                    var distinctElements2 = nextelement.Elements().Select(xx => xx).Distinct();

     //From 'element' excluding the 'StopoverSegs' node which by default always come as last node
                    var subelements = element.Elements().Take(distinctNodeName.Count() - 1);
 //From 'nextelement' excluding the 'StopoverSegs' node which by default always come as last node
                    var sub2 = nextelement.Elements().Take(distinctNodeName2.Count() - 1);
                    // Compare node name counts which are selected as distinct
                    if (distinctNodeName.Count() == distinctNodeName2.Count())
                    {
                        ArrayList fir = new ArrayList(); 
                        int arrcount = 0; ArrayList sec = new ArrayList();
                        //Add 'element' to array list for comparison
                        foreach (var firstSet in subelements)
                        {
                            fir.Add(firstSet.ToString()); arrcount++;
                        }
                        //Add 'nextelement' to array list for comparison
                        foreach (var secondSet in sub2)
                        {
                            sec.Add(secondSet.ToString());
                        }
    //comparison . I could not get through to compare  via SequenceEqual or other custom        
     //extension 
                        for (int i = 0; i < arrcount; i++)
                        {
                            if (fir[i].ToString().Trim() != sec[i].ToString().Trim())
                            {
                                GotEqual = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                GotEqual = true;
                            }
                        }

                            if (GotEqual)
                        {
           element.Add(nextelement.Elements().Except(element.Elements(), new ElementComparer()));
          skiptimes++;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            finalXML.Add(element);
        }
```

Comment: You may get an answer if you format your xml, post the expected xml, the code you have tried so far and ask about specific problem you have.

Answer (score -3):

This is horrible code, and I haven't had time to clean it up, but this works.

```
        var xDoc = XDocument.Parse("<and><restriction type=\"Stopovers_Type\" Name=\"STP\"><NbMaxOfStops>4</NbMaxOfStops><Charges1><FirstAmount Currency=\"AUD\">10.00</FirstAmount></Charges1><StopoversSegs><GeoSpec><Location1>AKL</Location1><Location2>CHC</Location2></GeoSpec><ChargeIndicator>1</ChargeIndicator></StopoversSegs><StopoversSegs><GeoSpec><Location1>LAX</Location1><Location2>RAR</Location2></GeoSpec><ChargeIndicator>1</ChargeIndicator></StopoversSegs></restriction><restriction type=\"Stopovers_Type\" Name=\"STP\"><NbMaxOfStops>2</NbMaxOfStops><NbOfOutboundStops>1</NbOfOutboundStops><NbOfInboundStops>1</NbOfInboundStops><Charges1><FirstAmountNbOf>1</FirstAmountNbOf><FirstAmount Currency=\"AUD\">301.00</FirstAmount><AdditionalAmountNbOf>1</AdditionalAmountNbOf><AdditionalAmount Currency=\"AUD\">151.00</AdditionalAmount></Charges1><StopoversSegs><NbOfStops>1</NbOfStops><GeoSpec><Location1>LAX</Location1></GeoSpec><InboundOutboundIndicator>I</InboundOutboundIndicator><ChargeIndicator>1</ChargeIndicator></StopoversSegs></restriction><restriction type=\"Stopovers_Type\" Name=\"STP\"><NbMaxOfStops>2</NbMaxOfStops><NbOfOutboundStops>1</NbOfOutboundStops><NbOfInboundStops>1</NbOfInboundStops><Charges1><FirstAmountNbOf>1</FirstAmountNbOf><FirstAmount Currency=\"AUD\">301.00</FirstAmount><AdditionalAmountNbOf>1</AdditionalAmountNbOf><AdditionalAmount Currency=\"AUD\">151.00</AdditionalAmount></Charges1><StopoversSegs><NbOfStops>1</NbOfStops><GeoSpec><Location1>SFO</Location1></GeoSpec><InboundOutboundIndicator>O</InboundOutboundIndicator><ChargeIndicator>2</ChargeIndicator></StopoversSegs></restriction></and>");
        var xDoc2 = XDocument.Parse("<and><restriction type=\"Stopovers_Type\" Name=\"STP\"><NbMaxOfStops>4</NbMaxOfStops><Charges1><FirstAmount Currency=\"AUD\">10.00</FirstAmount></Charges1><StopoversSegs><GeoSpec><Location1>AKL</Location1><Location2>CHC</Location2></GeoSpec><ChargeIndicator>1</ChargeIndicator></StopoversSegs><StopoversSegs><GeoSpec><Location1>LAX</Location1><Location2>RAR</Location2></GeoSpec><ChargeIndicator>1</ChargeIndicator></StopoversSegs></restriction><restriction type=\"Stopovers_Type\" Name=\"STP\"><NbMaxOfStops>2</NbMaxOfStops><NbOfOutboundStops>1</NbOfOutboundStops><NbOfInboundStops>1</NbOfInboundStops><Charges1><FirstAmountNbOf>1</FirstAmountNbOf><FirstAmount Currency=\"AUD\">301.00</FirstAmount><AdditionalAmountNbOf>1</AdditionalAmountNbOf><AdditionalAmount Currency=\"AUD\">151.00</AdditionalAmount></Charges1><StopoversSegs><NbOfStops>1</NbOfStops><GeoSpec><Location1>LAX</Location1></GeoSpec><InboundOutboundIndicator>I</InboundOutboundIndicator><ChargeIndicator>1</ChargeIndicator></StopoversSegs></restriction><restriction type=\"Stopovers_Type\" Name=\"STP\"><NbMaxOfStops>2</NbMaxOfStops><NbOfOutboundStops>1</NbOfOutboundStops><NbOfInboundStops>1</NbOfInboundStops><Charges1><FirstAmountNbOf>1</FirstAmountNbOf><FirstAmount Currency=\"AUD\">301.00</FirstAmount><AdditionalAmountNbOf>1</AdditionalAmountNbOf><AdditionalAmount Currency=\"AUD\">151.00</AdditionalAmount></Charges1><StopoversSegs><NbOfStops>1</NbOfStops><GeoSpec><Location1>SFO</Location1></GeoSpec><InboundOutboundIndicator>O</InboundOutboundIndicator><ChargeIndicator>2</ChargeIndicator></StopoversSegs></restriction></and>");

        xDoc.Root.Descendants().Where(w => w.Name == "StopoversSegs").Remove();

        var lsDistinct = xDoc.Root.Elements().Select(s => s.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();

        var lDistinct = lsDistinct.Select(s => Tuple.Create(s, XElement.Parse(s))).ToList();

        var lStopNodes = xDoc2.Root.Elements().Select(s => Tuple.Create(XElement.Parse(s.ToString()), XElement.Parse(s.ToString()))).ToList();

        foreach ( var stopNode in lStopNodes)
        {
            stopNode.Item1.Descendants("StopoversSegs").Remove();
        }

        var lStopNodesToDistinct = lStopNodes.Select(s => Tuple.Create(s.Item1.ToString(), s.Item2.Descendants("StopoversSegs"))).ToList();

        foreach (var distinct in lDistinct)
        {
            distinct.Item2.Add(lStopNodesToDistinct.Where(w => w.Item1 == distinct.Item1).Select(s => s.Item2.Nodes()).ToArray());

            var test = lStopNodesToDistinct.Where(w => w.Item1 == distinct.Item1).Select(s => s.Item2.Nodes()).ToArray();
        }


        xDoc.Root.Elements().Remove();

        xDoc.Root.Add(lDistinct.Select(s => s.Item2));
```

Comment: `Perform your grouping there.` Don't you think this is the question?

Comment: @L.B No, I didn't really think that was the question. The question seemed (to me) to be how do I do this in XML, my answer was don't. Convert it to a datatable and do it there, where it's far easier. But I updated the answer with some links that might help clear things up.

Comment: To parse an xml there are better ways like *XmlDocument* or *XDocument* classes, You only say *use this tool* but the question is how to merge the nodes, so how do you use your tool to achieve this?

Comment: below is the code                                                          var xml1 = XDocument.Parse(@""); var xml2 = XDocument.Parse(@""); xml1.Root.Add(xml2.Root.Elements().Except(xml1.Root.Elements(), new ElementComparer()));

Comment: Thanks Chuck for your solution. The 2 xmls that you have considered have attributs as  'type=\"Stopovers_Type\" Name=\"STP\"' can be different e.g. as 'type=\"Transfers_Type\" Name=\"TRF\"'. Also, the 'Stopovers' could be different e.g. as 'Transfers'. Thus I need a generic method to compare and merge if the 2 xmls are identical except for 'Stopovers' which will be different [if the other nodes are identical]. Also, there could be n number of 'restriction'nodes thus iteration is required. And, the 'restriction' nodes are within the 'and' root node.

Comment: @AjeetKumar The code above will remove the stopovers, and get the distinct restriction nodes without stopovers. Then it will find the stopovers that match those distinct restrictions and adds them to the distinct restriction.